# How to Switch Metro to desktop by windows api

Tags: visual-c++

I Want to Switch metro to desktop becasuse in metro my win32 window would not be the topmost.  I found these Way but can't work:
1. simulate win + D key by sendinput, it doesn't work in metro
2. minimize the window above my window, it doesn't work with some window

how can i  Switch Metro to desktop by windows api?

TKS